# How to create "calendar" effectively with Python(pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need to create a "calendar" for coupons of different bonds. The idea is the following: there are three types of coupon bonds. First type pays coupons annually, second pays coupons quarterly, third pays coupons every month. I am given the following table

***Table 1***

| Bond | Type | Release date | Maturity date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bond A | Quarterly | 2022-01-01 | 2032-01-01 |
| Bond B | Monthly | 2020-06-06 | 2025-06-06 |

In this table each row is unique and each bond appears only once, so no duplicates are in the table.

So, in the end I expect to get the table like this

***Table 2***

| Bond | Type | Release date | Maturity date | Coupon date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bond A | Quarterly | 2022-01-01 | 2032-01-01 | 2022-04-01 |
| Bond A | Quarterly | 2022-01-01 | 2032-01-01 | 2022-07-01 |
| Bond A | Quarterly | 2022-01-01 | 2032-01-01 | 2022-10-01 |
| Bond A | Quarterly | 2022-01-01 | 2032-01-01 | 2023-01-01 |

Obviously, this table should be much longer, but I hope the concept of expected result is clear.

Here I should note that I do not need date with day precision, I need to have correct year and month, that is why you will see that I made all coupon dates with first day of the month.

I tried using pandas.Timedelta for this task, but 'M'(month) and 'Y'(year) values were removed, so I have to deal without them somehow.

## My attempt to complete the task is the following:

My imports

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
```

So, table 1 is my dataframe. I've splitted it into three smaller frames based on bond types.
Note: all dates are in datetime64[ns] format

```
annual_df   = df[df.Type == 'Annually'].reset_index(drop = True)
quarter_ df = df[df.Type == 'Quarterly'].reset_index(drop = True)
month_df    = df[df.Type == 'Monthly'].reset_index(drop = True)
```

This is my code for annual coupon bonds
I go backwards because at maturity date coupond is definitely paid

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(columns={'Bond', 'Type', 'Release date', 'Maturity date', 'Coupon date'})
for i in annual_df.index:
    stop_date = annual_df['Release date'][i]
    _date     = annual_df['Maturity date'][i] # the date that will be passed into 'Coupon date' column
    c = 0 # a constant
    print(i, 'out of',  annual_df.index.max()) # to track the iteration
    while _date > stop_date:
        arr = {'Bond':annual_df.Bond[i], 'Type':annual_df.Type[i], 'Release date':stop_date,
               'Maturity date':annual_df['Maturity date'][i], 'Coupon date': _date}
        temp = temp.append(arr, ignore_index = True)
        c += 1
        _date = datetime.datetime(annual_df['Maturity date'][i].year - c, ['Maturity date'][i].month, 1)

annual_df = temp
```

So, this code runs about an hour on my dataset that contains 25000 distinct bonds, what is pretty a lot, but not as long as the following code for quarterly paid coupons

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(columns={'Bond', 'Type', 'Release date', 'Maturity date', 'Coupon date'})
for i in quarter_df.index:
    stop_date = quarter_df['Release date'][i]
    _date     = quarter_df['Maturity date'][i] # the date that will be passed into 'Coupon date' column
    c = 0 # a constant
    print(i, 'out of',  quarter_df.index.max()) # to track the iteration
    if quarter_df['Maturity date'][i].month < 4:
        while _date > stop_date:
            arr1 = {'Bond':annual_df.Bond[i], 'Type':annual_df.Type[i], 'Release date':stop_date,
               'Maturity date':annual_df['Maturity date'][i], 'Coupon date': _date}

            _date = datetime.datetime(annual_df['Maturity date'][i].year - c, 
                                     ['Maturity date'][i].month + 3,1)
            arr2 = {'Bond':annual_df.Bond[i], 'Type':annual_df.Type[i], 'Release date':stop_date,
               'Maturity date':annual_df['Maturity date'][i], 'Coupon date': _date}

            _date = datetime.datetime(annual_df['Maturity date'][i].year - c, 
                                     ['Maturity date'][i].month + 6,1)
            arr3 = {'Bond':annual_df.Bond[i], 'Type':annual_df.Type[i], 'Release date':stop_date,
               'Maturity date':annual_df['Maturity date'][i], 'Coupon date': _date}

            _date = datetime.datetime(annual_df['Maturity date'][i].year - c, 
                                     ['Maturity date'][i].month + 9,1)
            arr4 = {'Bond':annual_df.Bond[i], 'Type':annual_df.Type[i], 'Release date':stop_date,
               'Maturity date':annual_df['Maturity date'][i], 'Coupon date': _date}

            c += 1
            _date = datetime.datetime(annual_df['Maturity date'][i].year - c, 
                                     ['Maturity date'][i].month,1)
            temp = temp.append(arr1, ignore_index=True)
            temp = temp.append(arr2, ignore_index=True)
            temp = temp.append(arr3, ignore_index=True)
            temp = temp.append(arr4, ignore_index=True)

    elif quarter_df['Maturity date'][i].month > 3 and quarter_df['Maturity date'][i].month < 7:
            #the same if but just with different _date month values, literaly Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V
    elif quarter_df['Maturity date'][i].month > 6 and quarter_df['Maturity date'][i].month < 10:
            #again, the same
    else:
            #same
```

So this part, from my calculations, takes around 2 seconds per each iteration, and I have a dataset of 34000 rows for this exact code, what turns out to work for 18.3 hours in total.

Do you know how to optimize this code?
Do you know any other method to do the same but shorter and faster?

Comment: just a general comment; for offsetting dates by months or years, pandas offers [DateOffset](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a series of coupon dates for each row and then explode it:

```py
def coupon_dates(row: pd.Series):
    n = {"Monthly": 1, "Quarterly": 3, "Annually": 12}[row["Type"]]

    # Generate a series of coupon dates from Release date to Maturity date
    return pd.date_range(
        row["Release date"],
        row["Maturity date"],
        freq=pd.DateOffset(months=n),
        inclusive="right",
    )


df["Coupon date"] = df.apply(coupon_dates, axis=1)
df = df.explode("Coupon date")
```